# Database design for tracking events

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Looking for opinions on a design to track email events:
- queued
- delivered
- opened
- clicked
- bounced
- marked as spam

Some of the events above, will have unique information about them. For instance, the opened event will have ip & browser information, similarly, the click event will also contain the link clicked.

I'm thinking one table of each event, which has the corresponding email_id, with columns as needed (link_clicked, ip_address, etc).

My question really is, if I want to get the last 5 events of email id X, rather than querying each table and ordering by time and then selecting the last 5, would it be bad practice to have an intermediate table, email_events, which will be a polymorphic relation connecting them all up which will also contain a time column for ordering?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

NO!  One table, not one table per event.

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE id = ...
    FROM Events
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 5;
```

Gets the last 5 (or fewer) events.